# Unsafe parameter value in link_to href Rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I used brakeman for generating scanning reports in my application. It generated a Cross Site Scripting security warning in my view page as:

> Unsafe parameter value in link_to href near line 3: link_to("",
>   Instagram.authorize_url(:redirect_uri =>
>   ((Rails.application.config.custom.domain_url +
>   "instagram/callback/?edit=") + (params[:id].present? ? (params[:id]) :
>   ("")))), :id => "insta-sign-in-button")

This is my view:

```
<% if @instagram_oauth.nil? %>
  <h2>Connect to your Instagram account</h2>
  <%= link_to '', Instagram.authorize_url(:redirect_uri => Rails.application.config.custom.domain_url + 'instagram/callback/?edit=' + (params[:id].present? ? params[:id] : '')), :id => "insta-sign-in-button" %>
<% end %>
```

How to fix this warning?

Answer (score 1):

Warning clearly indicating that you are passing a parameter `params[:id]` to link_to directly, That can be dangerous.

Better to pass some object to it. Or if you can't do that you can pass local variable in your link_to to get rid of this warning. **But this is not a proper solution.**

```
url_id = params[:id].present? ? params[:id] : ''
```

And pass this in your link_to url.

Comment: Just putting the value into a local variable isn't going to remove the warning.